# #pragma warning disable, in Razor syntax, but only for catch statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I want to disable the warning of my catch statement, **but only of the catch statement**! The same way as in the .cs file!

**Important! :** I do not want to remove the **SystemException e** argument! My **specific demand** is to **specifically** suppress the waring of the catch statement with the **Razor** syntax. Same way as it works in a .cs file without razor.

**Initial situation:**

```
<div>
    @{
        try
        {
            //some code
            <div>yes</div>
        }
        catch (SystemException e)
        {
            <div>error</div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

I get:
[image] The variable 'e' is declared but never used

**a) If I put the `pragma` statements around the `catch`, I get following error:**

```
#pragma warning disable 0168
catch (SystemException e)
#pragma warning restore 0168
```

[image] Error    11  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   _Header.cshtml  72  13

**b) If I put a Razor-`@` before the `<div>` block, I get following error:**

```
@<div>error</div>
```

[image] Error    5   ; expected _Header.cshtml   1   1

**c) If I put a `;` after the `<div>` block, it seems OK, but when loading the site I get following compilation error:**

```
@<div>error</div>;
```

Compilation error:

```
Line 379:            #line default
Line 380:            #line hidden
Line 381:item => new System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult(__razor_template_writer => {
Line 382:
Line 383:BeginContext(__razor_template_writer, "~/Views/Shared/_Header.cshtml", 1947, 16, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are never using the catch exception, you could just do this:

```
<div>
@{
    try
    {
        //some code
        <div>yes</div>
    }
    catch
    {
        <div>error</div>
    }
}
</div>
```

Whilst I think wrapping pragmas around your catch simply to ignore a warning about an unused variable is, frankly, a hideous proposal (not only does it look ugly, but I think it reduces readability, and confuses matters - are you using the variable or not?), if you *really* need to do that, try this:

```
<div>
@{
    try
    {
        //some code
        throw new SystemException();
        <div>yes</div>
    }

    catch 
    (
    #pragma warning disable 0168
        SystemException e
    #pragma warning restore 0168
    )
    {
        <div>error</div>
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats clear, but I **specifically** want to suppress the warning!

Comment: Ok. Added a link to another post doing something that might help.

Comment: Thank you again, I read the other thread before, that works, but my specific demand would be, just to suppress the wanring of the catch line in Razor. Maybe there is a solution. Independent of the question if its useful to supress the warning or not. But nevertheless, it is a valid question, but for another topic..

Comment: Ok. I was aircoding previously - I've added a code block that seems to work on my machine.

Comment: Thank you, nice solution with minimal intrusion in the warning action!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the `e` variable, but still need to specifically catch `SystemException` exceptions, you can just use:

```
<div>
    @try
    {
        // Some code here.
    }
    catch (SystemException)
    {
        <div>
            A system error occurred.
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

There's no need to use `#pragma` to suppress the warning if you can avoid it with valid code. Warnings are there for a reason.